# Get the number of passed and failed tests with their name from command line

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am writing Python script which will run `mvn test` on different folders, and I want to get number of passed test and failed tests and their names from script.

Now I just have managed to run process and get it output

```
proc = subprocess.run(["mvn", "test", "-f", PROJ_PATH])
print(proc.stdout)
```

output:

```
   Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.715 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-12T18:59:11+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know that I can use regexp and try to parse output, but may be there are some more appropriate ways to incorporate with Maven from Python or Bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple solutions, but no direct one... they would all involve some parsing (XML or text file).

#### XML reports

This is probably the safest and simple route. Surefire generates by default XML reports inside [`target/surefire-reports`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportsDirectory). There is one XML file per test class, and this file contains the results of the execution of the tests in that class. This XML follows [a pre-defined XSD](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd) and guarantees a stable output.

Each XML file (for each test class) inside `target/surefire-reports` is named `TEST-${testClass}.xml` where `${testClass}` is replaced with the fully qualified name of the test class. Its relevant content for a test class of `my.test.MyTest` would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="my.test.MyTest" tests="4" errors="1" skipped="1" failures="1">
  <properties> <!-- omitted, contains system properties for the test --> </properties>
  <testcase name="test" classname="my.test.MyTest" time="0.096">
    <failure></failure>
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="test2" classname="my.test.MyTest" time="0.001">
    <error></error>
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="test3" classname="my.test.MyTest" time="0.002"/>
  <testcase name="test4" classname="my.test.MyTest" time="0">
    <skipped/>
  </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

(There are other attributes but they are not relevant here). Basically, the `<testsuite>` says there were 4 tests, which resulted in an error for 1, a failure for 1 and a skip for 1; so the remaining 1 was a success. More precisely, each `<testcase>` represent a test method through the `name` attribute, and the element inside represent its result. This can be parsed quite simply with regard to the 4 possible outcome for a test:

- failure (the assertions made in it were not verified): there is a `<failure>` element inside `<testcase>`.
- error (an exception was thrown, and it wasn't expected): there is a `<error>` element inside `<testcase>`.
- skip: there is a `<skipped>` element inside `<testcase>`.
- success: there is no element inside `<testcase>`.

If you want the fully qualified name of the test method, append the `classname` attribute (which is the qualified name of the test class) to the `name` attribute (which is the name of the test method).

#### Logs

If you configure the Surefire Plugin with the `plain` [`reportFormat`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportFormat) with

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

the logs will contain all the info wanted:

```
Running my.test.MyTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 1, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.169 sec <<< FAILURE! - in my.test.MyTest
test(my.test.MyTest)  Time elapsed: 0.112 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
    at my.test.MyTest.test(my.test.MyTest.java:16)

test2(my.test.MyTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception
    at my.test.MyTest.test2(my.test.MyTest.java:21)

test3(my.test.MyTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
test4(my.test.MyTest) skipped
```

You can then have lots of fun greping this file with a regular expression looking for `(.*)\((.*)\)\s+(?|(skipped)|Time elapsed:.*<<< (.*))`: method name of the test is in group 1, fully qualified class name in group 2 and group 3 contains the result; if group 3 is null, then it's a success.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where should I place <plugin><plugin>, in the <build> or <report>?

Comment: @LuchkoSerega Ah yes didn't mention that. It's in the `<build><plugins><plugin>` section, like shown here https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins.